# Why Split button dropdowns first default button element not working on firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox, cakephp, split

why click event is not perform on mozila firefox, on the  first button of Split button dropdowns which is i have to set default button and when i try to without open dropdown direct click on that default button it does not work on firefox, but it working fine on chrome, please give me sugessions.

See this Split button dropdowns code below:

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="btn-group dropdn-action">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><?php $url=$this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'Groups')); echo $this->Html->link('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;Add New Group','#',array('name'=>'add','id'=>'add','onclick'=>"check_perform_add('$url/add');",'escape'=>false));?></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="caret"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">             
                <li role="presentation"><?php echo $this->Html->link('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>&nbsp;Edit','#',array('name'=>'editallfrm','id'=>'editallfrm','onclick'=>"check_perform_edit('$url');",'escape'=>false));?></li>
                <li role="presentation"><?php echo $this->Html->link('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>&nbsp;Delete','#',array('name'=>'deleteallfrm','id'=>'deleteallfrm','onclick'=>'check_perform_delete();','escape'=>false));?></li>                
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add `<a>` inside `button`, using bootstrap you can use ` directly as shown below:

```
<a href="xxx" class="btn btn-default">text</a>
```

Hope it helps